# How do I add a sharepoint listitem with a content type using the GraphClient in an azure function

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to add a sharepoint list item with a content type using the graphclient.
I using this code:

```
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
ContentTypeInfo ct = new ContentTypeInfo()
            {
                ODataType = "microsoft.graph.contentTypeInfo",
                Id = config["AuditItemContentTypeId"]

            };
var listItem = new Microsoft.Graph.ListItem
            {
                ContentType = ct,
                Fields = new FieldValueSet
                {
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {"Title", "xxx"},
                        {"CreationTime", auditItem.CreationTime},
                        {"AuditItemId", auditItem.Id},// ID is used in sp
                }
             }
         ,
    };
   var addedItem = await graphClient.Sites[stc.CaptureToSiteId].Lists[stc.CaptureToListId].Items
                               .Request()
                               .AddAsync(listItem);
```

The addadsync fails with the message
2021-05-27T21:37:04.897 [Error] Executed 'ProcessAuditItem' (Failed, Id=d846ddc1-bb9d-4082-88b6-b6b3fa26afc8, Duration=507ms)Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Anyone have an ide what i've done wrong? Any docs on doing this with the graph client in c# (not sending raw JSON... im trying to use the classes porovided). Is ther a way to turn on some verbose logging in the graphclient?

Russell

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what is wrong with your code based on the information you have provided. Assuming you have checked that stc is not null: What kind of SharePoint field is AuditItemId? Also the exact ContentTypeId could be relevant. As far as I know, there is no additional logging that you can turn on. However, in the latest versions of the Graph SDK you can customize the GraphServiceClient to implement your own logging. First, create a class based on System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler:

```
public class ExtensiveLoggingDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IExtensiveLoggingService _extensiveLoggingService;

    public ExtensiveLoggingDelegatingHandler(
        IExtensiveLoggingService extensiveLoggingService)
        : base()
    {
        _extensiveLoggingService = extensiveLoggingService;
    }

    public ExtensiveLoggingDelegatingHandler(
        HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, 
        IExtensiveLoggingService extensiveLoggingService)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
        _extensiveLoggingService = extensiveLoggingService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        
        //add custom logging logic here
        await _extensiveLoggingService.DocumentMSGraphApiCall(request, response);

        return response;
    }
}
```

I am using Dependency Injection to inject custom logging into the DelegatingHandler. The logger just writes all info (request url, request header, request body, response header, ...) into a log file, if a certain log level is configured. The handler needs to be injected into the GraphServiceClient in order to be called upon request execution:

```
        var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers(
            someMicrosoftGraphIAuthenticationProvider);

        handlers.Add(new ExtensiveLoggingDelegatingHandler( _extensiveLoggingService));
     
        var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);

        var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);
```